# Getting undefined for selected index

Tags: jquery

I'm not sure if it's because I used jQuery to get the ref to the dropdown or what but my assumption is yes which is why the selected index is giving me undefined

```
var ddlMake = $('#<%=ddlMake.ClientID %>');
var makeid = ddlMake.options[ddlMake.selectedIndex].value;
```

so I get an error saying ddlMake.selectedIndex is undefined.

But if I use standard JS to ref that dropdown, then the ddlMake.selectedIndex works fine and I get a value

```
var ddlMake = document.getElementById('<%=ddlMake.ClientID %>');
var makeid = ddlMake.options[ddlMake.selectedIndex].value;
```

So is it if you use jQuery to get a ref to some element in the DOM, are you required to also use jQuery methods further to use that element such as get data from it or manipulate it or whatever?

I guess you can't mix both..such as if you get a ref by using jquery, you can't then use standard js methods against it?  Just curious about this because it's an important limitation if so.  Not that I want to use standard JS as I'm using jquery but just curious since I did come across this pain and want to figure out the answer here.

Comment: sorry I'd love to accept both your answers but I chose who came up with the rreason first and that was mu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selectedIndex` is an attribute of the DOM element but `$('#x')` returns a jQuery object. You can get the DOM object using `[0]` though:

```
var ddlMake = $('#<%=ddlMake.ClientID %>');
var makeid  = ddlMake[0].options[ddlMake[0].selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: hmm on the contrary what's interesting is I notice if you do this: var ddlPaintType = document.getElementById('<%=ddlPaintType.ClientID %>'); you can use jQuery methods on raw DOM elements?

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: No, you can't use jQuery methods on raw DOM objects. What are you doing to `ddlPaintType`?

Answer (score 2):

`$(...)` return a jQueryu object, not a DOM element.
You need to use [jQuery methods](http://api.jquery.com/) on it.

You can write `$(...)[0]` to get the raw DOM element contained in thw jQuery object, nut that defeats the purpose of jQuery.

Using jQuery, you can write something like

```
$('#<%=ddlMake.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
```

Comment: thanks, and to get the text value of the dropdown I assume text();